# Spring 2017 - localizationService method UTCToWallTime returns No dateTime from around 17th Feb, 2017

Tags: lightning-aura-components, datetime, localization

```
$A.localizationService.UTCToWallTime(date_utc, localeTimeZone, function(convertedWalltime) {
               console.log('convertedWalltime ' + convertedWalltime);
               console.log('Time:' + $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(convertedWalltime, datetimeFormat, userLocaleLang));
               });
```

- localizationService method UTCToWallTime returns empty braces {} from around 17th Feb, 2017
- localizationService method formatDateTime returns current browser time always.

Any one facing same issue? This is being observed in QA Orgs and Not in our Prod Orgs. Not sure if they have different sub versions of Spring 2017.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also having the same issue with $A.localizationService.formatDateTime returning the current date and time.

Comment: @svenf
I have raised a case with Salesforce and still waiting for solution.

I was asked to disable **critical update** related to **LockerService** and test if $A.localizationService methods are working as expected, It worked. But we cant disable the LockerService critical update to fix this issue.

svenf, Is there any luck at your end?

Comment: Since I was already using the library moment.js for other date manipulations, I am using that library to do the conversions and the formatting.

Comment: @svenf I had few problems with moment.js and IE, No issues when used with Chrome though. Thanks.

Comment: **Same code in Description is now working as expected** from 1st Week of March 17.
Not sure if some thing got updated in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code in Description is now working in all Orgs as expected from 1st Week of March '17. 
Nothing else was pointed out as part of Salesforce-Case analysis.
Not sure if some thing got updated in Salesforce.